# Average value of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry, expected-value, trigonometric-integrals

Suppose I have to find out $\langle \sin^2\theta\rangle$ and $\langle\cos^2\theta\rangle$.

What I do normally would be :

$$\langle\sin^2\theta\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta d\theta=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\langle\cos^2\theta\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2\theta d\theta=\frac{1}{2}$$

However, in a question they have asked us to do the same thing, but mentioned that $\theta$ is the polar angle and $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle.

Is the answer going to be the same in this case. I know that the limits would change from $0\rightarrow \pi$ or from $\frac{-\pi}{2}\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$, and I'd divide by $\pi$ instead of $2\pi$. However, the answer should be the same, and equal to $1/2$.

However, some sources suggest that since the word 'polar' angle us used for $\theta$, apart from this change in limits, we must also replace $d\theta$ by $\sin\theta d\theta$, and instead of dividing by $\pi$, we should do the following :

$$\langle\sin^2\theta\rangle=\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^3\theta d\theta}{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta}=\frac{2}{3}$$

$$\langle\cos^2\theta\rangle=\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^2\theta\sin\theta d\theta}{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta}=\frac{1}{3}$$

This second method doesn't make any sense to me, and I don't see why we need to this, instead of what we did in the first case. Any help in understanding why this happens, would be highly appreciated. I don't even know if this second method is valid at all.

Some people say that we do this second thing, since we are solving in spherical coordinates, as the word 'polar angle' is used, but I don't see why this extra term would show up, and why would the expectation value of these functions change depending on cartesian or polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the second interpretation is the correct one. Usually with

$$
\langle \bullet \rangle  
$$

one indicates the expectation value over a normalized measure. In this case it seems you are being asked to find the average of certain quantities over the two-dimensional sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Whereas your first interpretation is the average of certain quantities over the  one-dimensional circle (in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

You can compute said averages using symmetry arguments. Denote by $(x,y,z)$ a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then under the usual spherical coordinates

$$
z =  \cos(\theta)
$$

Hence

\begin{align}
\langle \cos(\theta)^2  \rangle &= \langle z^2  \rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{3}  \langle x^2 + y^2 + z^2  \rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}

Likewise

\begin{align}
\langle \sin(\theta)^2  \rangle &= \langle x^2 + y^2  \rangle \\
&= \frac{2}{3}  \langle x^2 + y^2 + z^2  \rangle \\
&= \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: A simple interpretation of this answer means that if you average something that depends on the polar angle one should give more weight to the quantity at the equator as opposed to the quantity at the poles. That is assuming a uniform density distribution on the sphere.

Comment: @Andrei yes I suppose. That is also the essence of the measure concentration phenomenon, though here only at dimension $d=3$.

Comment: @Andrei, yeah I understand that for a distribution of points over the surface or the volume of a sphere. However, I don't understand why the same is true for an angle. The $\theta$ angle is defined with respect to the $z$ axis here. So it should behave as an other angle, like the case in two dimensions, as Icv pointed out.

Comment: @Andrei if we average something that depends on the polar angle, like the distribution of points or arcs or chords or something, we should use this measure. However, I don't see why the measure is important, when we are averaging over the polar angle itself. This angle seems to be like any other angle, and the word polar doesn't seem to make a difference here.

Comment: Suppose you want to get the average of $f(\theta,\phi)$ over the sphere. It is important that it's over the entire sphere, and not a circle on the sphere. Then $$\langle f(\theta,\phi)\rangle=\frac1{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi\int_0^\pi f(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta d\theta$$Just use $f(\theta,\phi)=\cos^2\theta$. Note that $4\pi$ is the surface area of the sphere of radius $1$, and the surface element is $dS=\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$. So you do a weighted average, where the weight is the surface area.